# Amdatu JPA (bndtools, felix DM) not resolving DataSource service

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, bndtools, amdatu, felix-dependency-manager

So I was loosely following the Amdatu JPA video tutorial and I almost got it working...

At a glance everything seems to be fine, only DataSource service is not resolved and I don't know why. It seems to me that it is registered. So how would I go debugging this, there should be some way to debug this, right? 
When starting I have this in msg log:

```
[CM Configuration Updater (Update: pid=org.amdatu.jpa.datasourcefactory.dd8bf61e-01b1-4732-9b0c-bba96e1f5aff)] DEBUG org.amdatu.jpa.datasourcefactory - ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [javax.sql.DataSource] - org.amdatu.jpa.datasourcefactory
```

Output of "dm":

```
[5] org.amdatu.jpa.datasourcefactory
  org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory(service.pid=org.amdatu.jpa.datasourcefactory) registered
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
  javax.sql.DataSource(validationQuery=SELECT 1,name=ManagedDS,driverName=postgresql,serviceName=ManagedDS) registered
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
    org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory (osgi.jdbc.driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver) service required available
    javax.transaction.TransactionManager service required available
```

So the output above should mean that DataSource is registered, right?

```
[31] org.amdatu.jpa.extender
  org.amdatu.jpa.extender.PersistenceBundleManager() registered
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
    javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider service required available
    active (Meta-Persistence=*) bundle optional available
  java.lang.Object(bundle=32) registered
    org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional available
    org.amdatu.jpa.extender.PersistenceBundleManager service required available
  org.amdatu.jpa.extender.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl@7175ee92 unregistered
    javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider (javax.persistence.provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider) service required available
    javax.sql.DataSource (name=ManagedDS) service required unavailable
```

Everything further that depends on DataSource is obviously not resolved

```
    javax.persistence.EntityManager service required unavailable
```

So what I don't get is why is DataSource not resolved there? I checked and it seems it is registered with property name=ManagedDS, but I am quite new to Felix DS so I am not really sure what is happening here.

I also tried adding this

```
    @ServiceDependency(filter="(name=ManagedDS)")
private volatile DataSource ds;
```

to one of my services, but that too cannot be resolved. Thanks for any help regarding this, but what I would be most grateful of would be a way to debug and solve this myself.

Comment: Which version of Amdatu JPA are you using? And can you also post your datasource configuration file?

Comment: Well I followed the video tutorial. Version for which bundle exactly? There are quite a few of them... everything is from amdatu repos, felix dm latest v3, jta latest v1, amdatu jpa extender is 2.0.1. Anyway I pushed everything to github https://github.com/Neikius/amdatu_jpa_test.git. Will try to set all my versions exact. Also I've included ops4j postgres DS factory since I initially suspected that.

Comment: Oh and I've used R5 bootstrap to help myself a bit. I've figured it out though, I had to remove Import-Package: javax.sql;version=1.0.0 which was suggested video. Now I have problem using @ServiceDependency on my TestRepo. Probably because my Repo is providing ManagedTransactional not Repo. If I decide to provide Repo interface then I have problem with the transactional stuff.

Comment: Ok project in git all fixed up. Couldn't get modelgen to work, hope it helps someone. Still interested in recommendations for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Amdatu video tutorial suggested I should add

```
Import-Package: javax.sql;version=1.0.0
```

to my bundles. I tried removing that and it works (I did that when it stopped resolving that import after I set all versions to small ranges. Still don't know why it did that and wish that I tried that sooner)

So my guess as to why it works now - packages in my OSGi container were probably using two different versions/instances of javax.sql.DataSource. Probably one from postgres package and other someplace else (system?). Maybe one of the OSGi gurus can comment on this and clear it up?

Another sub-question is as that video suggested it is a good thing to add that import, what can I do to make it work or if it not important should I just not bother?